# How to reuse a layout in the QGIS print composer layout on different pages?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, template

I've got a map template that I've created in the QGIS print composer on page 1. It includes various objects like text boxes, images (north arrow), scalebar and legend. I want to use the same template on page 2, 3 and so on.  I've tried to select all the map objects, then copy and past them on to another page.  However all objects paste at the position of the cursor, meaning I then have to place them in their proper locations manually, so that is no good.

How can I easily replicate the map design on subsequent pages?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Edit -> "Paste in Place", or the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + V. This will place the items on the current page but maintaining their original position relative to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using the duplicate print composer option from the composer drop down?

Comment: This does appear to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It's a clear answer, if you are familiar with the program. 
The OP asks How to reuse a layout in the QGIS print composer layout on different pages?
You can duplicate any Print Composer and this duplicate includes all the images, labels, layouts, etc that were in the original.

Comment: A question is not an answer and your contribution has a question mark at the end. ;) If you have tested your method and found that it works and is a solution to the problem, then lay out the steps of the solution. If you have to make assumptions because OP didn't ask unambiguously (which is the case), then also state your assumptions about OP's intentions.

Comment: I just tested the premise of your question. It creates a new layout which is identical to the current one, instead of just adding another page to the current layout. These are distinctively different things.

Comment: My answer was over 2 years ago. QGIS has changed a lot since then, including changes to print layouts. It was correct at the time. If you know another way to do it in the more recent version, I'm sure there are still people who would like to know how to do it.

Comment: This is indeed an answer. I had a similar issue and this solution got it resolved.